# Problem to load .csv files into Apache Cassandra with Python

Tags: python, ubuntu, cassandra, cql

I'm trying to load a .csv file with Python into Apache Cassandra database.
The command "COPY" integrated with session.execute seems don't work.
It gives an unexpected indent in correspondance of =',' but...I red something about and I found that the command COPY in this way is not supported.

In this script time_test and p are two float variables

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

cluster = Cluster()

session = cluster.connect('myKEYSPACE')


rows = session.execute('COPY table_test (time_test, p) 
                        from'/home/mypc/Desktop/testfile.csv' with delimiter=',' and header=true;
                       ')
                                                                     

print('DONE')
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

Main problem here is that `COPY` is not a CQL command, but a `cqlsh` command, so it couldn't be executed via `session.execute`.

I recommend to use [DSBulk](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/index.html) to load data into Cassandra - it's very flexible, performant, and doesn't require programming. For simplest case, when you have direct mapping of columns in header of CSV file into column names in database, then the command-line will be very simple:

```
dsbulk load -url file.csv -k keyspace -t table -header true
```

There is a series of blog posts about DSBulk that covers a lot of topics:

- https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/03/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading
- https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/04/datastax-bulk-loader-more-loading
- https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/04/datastax-bulk-loader-common-settings
- https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/06/datastax-bulk-loader-unloading
- https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/07/datastax-bulk-loader-counting
- https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/12/datastax-bulk-loader-examples-loading-other-locations

Comment: thank you...but...I need to use datastax? Cause I'm using APC on my ubuntu

Comment: No, it should work with any supported Cassandra version

Comment: and no, it's not only the one way, but it's the better way than manually written code.
P.S. btw, `COPY` isn't very scalable & buggy - that's was one of the reasons for DSBulk creation