# DatastaxBulk loader problem with null headers

Tags: csv, ubuntu, cassandra, datastax

I have a .csv file to load on Apache Cassandra with DatastaxBulk Loader. So, I have 10 columns to load, every column has a float values but the first one have no header.

So, many timest I have and error that consist in failure load for the table because I have to map all headers...I don't know how solve this situation. Somen suggestion? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Without header, DSBulk doesn't know how to map values from CSV into your table.  So you must to use the `-m` option to provide the mapping between CSV columns & columns of the table, like this:

```sh
dsbulk load -url path.csv -k keyspace -t table -header false \
  -m "0=table_col1, 1=table_col2, 2=..."
```

P.S. I already posted links to the blog posts about DSBulk in [answer to your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64666874/problem-to-load-csv-files-into-apache-cassandra-with-python), so just look into the first two of them.